# How do I move a Drupal site from WAMP server to a live server?

Tags: database

I'm a newbie with this so am having quite a bit of trouble. I've created a Drupal site in WAMP Server and am raedy to move the site to my hosting with Heart Internet.

I've copied C:/Wamp/www/mywebsite into a zip folder and uploaded/unzipped into my hosting space so the files are uploaded successfully.

I then went into phpMyAdmin on my computer and exported my database. I then created a blank database on my web hosting on the live server. this database username is c150-drupal and i generated a random password. I then clicked 'restore' on my new blank database and selected the database that I exported from WAMP. however I keep getting the error message below:

ERROR 1044 (420000) at line 22: access denied for user 'c150-drupal'@'%' to 'postcodedatabase'

I'm so confused how I should be exporting mysql databases in order to upload them to my webserver. Also is it acceptable to export a database from WAMP in order to use as a backup incase anything goes wrong so I could import the database back into WAMP?

Thank you,.

Comment: Have you changed your username and password in settings.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check your user privilege on your production server because you can't do this action.

This thread deals with your problem : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838777/error-1044-42000-access-denied-for-user-localhost-to-database-db

Answer (score 0):

I take it you're using phpMyAdmin on the hosting server as well? 
make sure the DB names are the same for the new/empty one and the one you exported from - and if you manually changed the .sql file, make sure you changed the name in all places (CREATE and USE queries);

also check that the user has appropriate permissions for the new/empty DB - the hosting services often have it not in phpMyAdmin, but at the came place where you create DBs and users - look for something like "Add User To Database", and do exactly that - add the user to the DB with enough permissions to create/write

hope this helps